# fullcalendar.js - Insert for loop into modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar.js in my project and right now everything works fine except my modal window. I am inserting data from my database into the fullcalendar.js! Those data are displayed correctly in my calendar. If I click on an event a modal opens and there I want those data to be displayed.

I am using a for-loop to achieve this but it is not working as it should. It seems as the for-loop does not know which data it should display inside the modal window therefore all entries are displayed. Here is a screenshot of what it looks right now:

[image]

So if I click on an event, a modal opens with all entries, but what I want to achieve is, that only those entries are shown which are from the event that I have clicked. Here is my code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($) {

        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });
        });

        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

<?php
        print "var date = new Date();\n";
        print "var d = date.getDate();\n";
        print "var m = date.getMonth()-1;\n";
        print "var y = date.getFullYear();\n";
        print "var unixTimestamp = Date.now(); // in milliseconds;"

?>

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            //isRTL: true,
             buttonHtml: {
                prev: '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                next: '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
            },

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
<?php
            $dates=getPcalInfoOfHour($gl_userid,0,0);

            print "events: [\n";

            for ($x=0;$x<count($dates["id"]);$x++) {
                print "  {\n";
                print " title: '".$dates["title"][$x]."',\n";
                print " start: new Date(".date("Y",$dates["start"][$x]).", ".(date("n", $dates["start"][$x]) - 1).", ".date("j",$dates["start"][$x]).", ".date("G",$dates["start"][$x]).", ".date("i",$dates["start"][$x]).",0,0),\n";
                print " end: new Date(".date("Y",$dates["end"][$x]+1).", ".(date("n", $dates["end"][$x]+1) - 1).", ".date("j",$dates["end"][$x]+1).", ".date("G",$dates["end"][$x]+1).", ".date("i",($dates["end"][$x]+1)).",0,0),\n";
                print " allDay: false,\n";
                print "durationEditable : false,\n";
                print " className: 'label-info',\n";
                if ($dates["type"][$x]=="PM") {print "backgroundColor: '#000000',\n";}
                if ($dates["type"][$x]=="AM") {print "backgroundColor: '#D15B47',\n";}
                if ($dates["type"][$x]=="SM") {print "backgroundColor: '#FFB752',\n";}
                if ($dates["type"][$x]=="S") {print "backgroundColor: '#87B87F',\n";}
                if ($dates["type"][$x]=="SS") {print "backgroundColor: '#4F99C6',\n";}
                if ($dates["type"][$x]=="MJ") {print "backgroundColor: '#A069C3',\n";}
                if ($dates["type"][$x]=="PR") {print "backgroundColor: '#5A5A5A'\n";}
                if ($x<(count($dates["id"])-1)) {
                    print "  },\n";
                } else {
                    print "  }\n";
                }
            }

            print "]\n";
            timeFormat: 'h:mm'
?>
            ,
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
            drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
                var $extraEventClass = $(this).attr('data-class');

                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                if($extraEventClass) copiedEventObject['className'] = [$extraEventClass];

                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }

            }
            ,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {



                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            }
            ,
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                //display a modal
                var modal =
                '<div class="modal fade">\
                  <div class="modal-dialog">\
                   <div class="modal-content">\
                     <div class="modal-body">\
                     <?php for ($x=0;$x<count($dates["id"]);$x++) { ?>
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-top:-10px;">&times;</button>\
                        <label> <strong>Topic:</strong> <?php echo $dates["type"][$x] ?></label>\
                        <label> <strong>Selected Start:</strong> <?php echo $dates["start"][0]?></label>\
                        <label> <strong>Selected End:</strong> <?php echo $dates["end"][0] ?></label>\
                        <label> <strong>Title:</strong> <?php echo $dates["title"][0] ?></label>\
                        <label> <strong>Location:</strong> <?php echo $dates["location"][0] ?></label>\
                        <label> <strong>Address:</strong> <?php echo $dates["adress"][0] ?></label>\
                        <label> <strong>Phone:</strong> <?php echo $dates["phone"][0] ?></label>\
                     <?php } ?>
                     </div>\
                     <div class="modal-footer">\
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i> Close Window</button>\
                     </div>\
                  </div>\
                 </div>\
                </div>';

                var modal = $(modal).appendTo('body');

                modal.modal('show').on('hidden', function(){
                    modal.remove();
                });

                console.log(calEvent.id);
                console.log(jsEvent);
                console.log(view);

                // change the border color just for fun
                //$(this).css('border-color', 'red');

            }

            });

        })
        </script>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? What should my code look like so that it is working?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same scenario as this. What I did was use fullcalendar's built in clickHandler JavaScript functions to get the ID of the calendar item.

Then I used an AJAX call to my PHP file to pull the relevant item details from the database and then append them to the modal.

Comment: can you show me in my code what I need to change? I am not good at js functions or JAVA and therefore I have no idea what my code should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path, just the Json created needed to be fix please check the below code used in the events option in fullcalender.js

```
events:function(start, end, callback){

            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: SITEROOT+'/controller/mycalendar/events.json.php',
                 data: {action:'getevents',view:$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name,location:$("#location").val()},
                 success: function(result){
                    var events = [];
                    if(result){
                                $.each(result,function(i, item){

                                events.push({
                                id:result[i].id,
                                title:result[i].title,
                                start:result[i].start,
                                end:result[i].end,
                                url:result[i].url,
                                color:result[i].color,
                                textColor:result[i].textColor,
                                allDay:result[i].allDay
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    callback(events);
                 }
            });
        }
```

Comment: I looked at the fullcalendar.js but I cannot find the above code? What exactly do I need to do @Tejas Patil?

Comment: With reference to the code that you have posted the for loop that you have its the same i have posted the only difference is that i have used Ajax call to get the events data, i suggest you try the same.

Comment: Still not get the code to work as it should :(! May you edit my code with your code and re-post it so that I can try if your code is working and to see what my code should look like